# How to return the text node in the jQuery object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My question is, how would I return the text string "yahoo.com" from the jQuery object var link?

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com">yahoo.com</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var link = $('a');


alert(link.text);

console.log(link);
```

Comment: Do `link.text()`. Its a function.

Comment: jQuery's documentation is quite good. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

Give your link an `id` so you don't select all links, then use `.text()`.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" id="yahoo-link">yahoo.com</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $link = $("#yahoo-link");
console.log($link.text());
```